# Does there exist a tetrahedron, so that every edge is the side of an obtuse angle of a face?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have the following the question with me:

> "Does there exist a tetrahedron, so that every edge is the side of an obtuse angle of a face?"

The problem looks easy but I am unable to prove it. Any help please

Comment: FYI, this problem appears to be from "Problem Solving Strategies" by Arthur Engel. ([Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=IJLzBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48))

Comment: Well it actually is, but I didnt understand the solution very well, it was short and mentioned the only required point, didnt understand it fully actualy

Comment: I'd only provided a reference in case someone thought this might have originated in a contest or something. I didn't even check that link to see that there were solutions. :)  But, now that you mention that you've seen a solution that you didn't fully understand ... When such a thing happens, you should include the known solution as part of your question, and also try to convey why it is unsatisfactory to you. This will help answerers avoid wasting everyone's time duplicating that solution; they may also be able to clarify the solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Blue. Will make sure to do that. As of now, I actually had a problem which you explained in the last sentence of your solution. It was obvious but didnt strike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the tetrahedron $ABCD$ be such that edge $\overline{BC}$ is opposite an obtuse angle at $A$ in face $\triangle ABC$. If the other edges of that face —$\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$— are both opposite obtuse angles, then those angles must be at $D$ in faces $\triangle ADB$ and $\triangle ADC$. But then, $\overline{AD}$, the edge common to those faces, cannot be opposite an obtuse angle.

Comment: The way I read it, each edge must be *adjacent* to an obtuse angle in at least one face, not opposite

Comment: I think you're right, and this explains why my too-simple counting argument isn't what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

The tetrahedron has only four faces, so at most four obtuse angles. At most four of the six edges can be opposite to these angles.

Comment: I've been doing something of a dive into metric properties of tetrahedra lately, so I completely missed this simple counting argument! *sheesh* :)

Comment: I wondered (and still wonder) if I didn't misunderstand the question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $AC$ and $BC$ form an obtuse angle in $\triangle ABC$. Then $AB$ has to be a side of the obtuse angle of $\triangle ABD$. Assume that $\angle DAB$ is obtuse. Then $BD$ is a side of the obtuse angle of $\triangle BCD$. If $\angle BDC$ is obtuse, then $BC > BD > AB$, a contradiction.

Therefore $\angle CBD$ is obtuse and $CD$ forms an obtuse angle either with $AC$ or with $AD$. In the first case, $AD > CD > BD$, a contradiction. In the second case, $AC > CD > BD > AB$, also a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever $AB$ is the side of an obtuse angle in $\triangle ABC$, one of the other sides is longer ($BC$ if the obtuse angle is $\angle A$, or $AC$ if the obtuse angle is $\angle B$).

So the longest edge of the tetrahedron can't be the side of an obtuse angle.